# Get Every Tuesday of the month with Coldfusion

Tags: date, coldfusion

I'm currently working with jquery FullCalendar plugin to create a specific calendar.

One of my tasks I have to work out is how to get any given specific day for the month.

I'm currently using Coldfusion 10 for the server side so I'm wondering is there any specific way of getting every instance of a Tuesday into an array of dates?

Ideally I would like to do this on the server side and populate the calendar plugin.

My issue is primarily trying to source every specific day of a calendar month.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The [`firstXDayOfMonth()`](http://www.cflib.org/udf/FirstXDayOfMonth) UDF on CFLlib allows you to find the first of a given day-of-week in a given month. From there you just need to loop from that date adding `7` each iteration until the month is no long the selected month.

```
theMonth = month(now());
startDate = firstXDayOfMonth(3, theMonth, year(now()));
tuesdays = [];
for (date=startDate; month(date) == theMonth; date +=7){
    arrayAppend(tuesdays, dateAdd("s",0, date)); // this just converts date from a number back to a date
}
writeDump(tuesdays);
```

Update:
Actually the approach for that UDF on CFLib is terrible. Use this variation instead:

```
function firstXDayOfMonth(dayOfWeek,month,year){
    var firstOfMonth    = createDate(year, month,1);
    var dowOfFirst      = dayOfWeek(firstOfMonth);
    var daysToAdd       = (7 - (dowOfFirst - dayOfWeek)) MOD 7;
    var dow = dateAdd("d", daysToAdd, firstOfMonth);
    return dow;
}
```

I'll update the UDF on cflib a bit later: I need to write some decent unit tests for it first, and am a bit busy @ the moment.

Answer (score 0):

### *The Short Version:*

At this time, there is not a function in CF that gets all the Tuesdays. But here's an easy way to do it:

```
// assuming a year and month are defined already
var firstDayOfMonth = createDate( year, month, 1 );
var targetDayOfWeek = 3; // Tuesday is 3 if Sunday is 1
var dayOfWeekArray = []; // This is the outcome.

// loop through each day of the month adding the target days to the array.
for( i = 1; i LTE daysInMonth( firstDayOfMonth ); i++){
  var loopingDate = createDate( year, month, i );
  if( dayOfWeek( loopingDate ) == targetDayOfWeek ){
    ArrayAppend( dayOfWeekArray, loopingDate );
  }
}
```

`dayOfWeekArray` is an array of every Tuesday of a month.

---

### *More Detail:*

Your title and post seem to conflict as far as what you're looking for, so I'm going to stick with the title, since that's why I came here...

Here's what you can do to find all the Tuesdays in a month:

- Create a date Object
- Loop through the days in the target month using the date Object
- If the current day is Tuesday, add it to an array
- Boom, you got all the Tuesdays of a month in an array

Here's the code I used (cfscript):

```
// assuming a year and month are defined already
var firstDayOfMonth = createDate( year, month, 1 );
var dayOfWeekArray = [];
var targetDayOfWeek = 3; // Tuesday is 3 if Sunday is 1. Do a quick writeDump in the loop if you're not sure.

for( i = 1; i LTE daysInMonth( firstDayOfMonth ); i++){
  var loopingDate = createDate( year, month, i );
  if( dayOfWeek( loopingDate ) == targetDayOfWeek ){
    ArrayAppend( dayOfWeekArray, datePart( "d", loopingDate );
    // ArrayAppend( dayOfWeekArray, loopingDate ); - use this if you'd rather have the whole date object
  }
}
```

This gives you `dayOfWeekArray` which will be the date of each Tuesday of a particular month. For instance, this month (Jan 2019) will be `[1, 8, 15, 22, 29]`. You can change this to be the entire date object if you want - that's what I did in the short version at the top.